# How to display the values stored in a cell in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, cell

I have G=cell(3,1)

I'm storing two values e.g. `100 | 500` in each cell. Whenever I try to print the value  `G(1)` for example, I get :

```
ans = 

    [2x1 double]
```

How can I display the actual cell content rather than `[2x1 double]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cell2mat(G(1))
```

This should solve your problem. You can also use cell2mat(G) and it will concatenate all the matrices in G (but all the elements in G must have the same size)

Answer (score 0):

`G{1}` will give you the content of the first cell. Command `reshape([G{:}]',[],length(G))'` will give you the content of the entire cell.